# data inserted in mysql table not in chronological order

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP script which runs every 1 minute (cron) and queries a remote API, gets a number and inserts it in a mysql table. Problem is, not every row in the table is inserted in chronological order.

example:

```
  id    AddDate                     Price
1864    2017-09-07 05:25:01.000000  439
1865    2017-09-07 05:26:01.000000  439
1866    2017-09-07 05:28:01.000000  439
1867    2017-09-07 05:29:01.000000  459
1868    2017-09-07 05:30:01.000000  539
1869    2017-09-07 05:31:01.000000  536
1870    2017-09-07 05:32:01.000000  436
1871    2017-09-07 05:33:01.000000  537
1872    2017-09-07 05:27:01.000000  539
1873    2017-09-07 05:34:01.000000  456
1874    2017-09-07 05:35:01.000000  456
```

as you can see after `2017-09-07 05:26:01` entry comes `2017-09-07 05:28:01` and `2017-09-07 05:27:01` comes much later.

Here's the php script:

```
$AddDate = trim(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$Price = getprice();

$adddata_PRST = $MYPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO tblData (AddDate, Price) VALUES(:AddDate, :Price)");
$adddata_PRST->bindValue(":AddDate", $AddDate);
$adddata_PRST->bindValue(":Price", $Price);
$adddata_PRST->execute() or die($MYPDO->errorInfo());
```

i'm thinking it's not a cron issue but the fact that i'm not using `$MYPDO->beginTransaction();` and `$MYPDO->commit();` ? Or can it be something else ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of sending current time from application code, you can use NOW() in sql query directly. This will ensure that time is in right order. There maybe some lag in your query formation (in application code) and execution (at MySQL server end), causing this time anomaly.

Comment: Madhur is right, using NOW() would help. But does it really matter? You can read the data out in the right order using ORDER BY. SQL tables are not inherently ordered, after all.

Comment: @ADyson sure I can order by DATE, but shouldn't the id and Date order be the same in this case in the first place ? I'll try with NOW() thanks.

Comment: "shouldn't the id and Date order be the same"...since you're querying a remote API I would guess this is probably because the response time from that API is variable, and/or the requests run asynchronously. So the order in which the records are inserted into the database is perhaps not totally predictable. It won't be SQL's fault, that's for sure. But as long as you have a way to order it when you view it, it's really not a big problem to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line

```
$adddata_PRST = $MYPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO tblData (AddDate, Price) VALUES(:AddDate, :Price)");
```

With

```
$adddata_PRST = $MYPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO tblData (AddDate, Price) VALUES(NOW(), :Price)");
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks